# Reducing compute time for Anagram word search

Tags: python

The code below is a brute force method of searching a list of words and creating sub-lists of any that are Anagrams.

Searching the entire English dictionary is prohibitively time consuming so I'm curious of anyone has tips for reducing the compute complexity of the code?

```
def anogramtastic(anagrms):
    d = []
    e = []
    for j in range(len(anagrms)):
        if anagrms[j] in e:
            pass
        else:
            templist = []
            tester = anagrms[j]        
            tester = list(tester)
            tester.sort()
            tester = ''.join(tester)
            for k in range(len(anagrms)):
                if k == j:
                    pass
                else:
                    testers = anagrms[k]        
                    testers = list(testers)
                    testers.sort()
                    testers = ''.join(testers)
                    if testers == tester:
                        templist.append(anagrms[k])
                        e.append(anagrms[k])
            if len(templist) > 0:
                templist.append(anagrms[j])
                d.append(templist)
    d.sort(key=len,reverse=True) 
    return d

print(anogramtastic(wordlist))
```

Comment: An obvious answer would be to use multiprocessing, but other than that I don't really see how to make this more efficient... Maybe restrict your loop over `k` to only words that have the same length as that of the one you are looking anagrams for?

Comment: Another comment: why do you need both `e` and `temp_list`? It looks like they are just the same.

Comment: have you tried testing prefixes? Like, for example, if your 2 first letters are `bb`, you won't find any word no matter how many letters you put after.

Comment: @njzk2 But anagrams need not have the same prefix?

Comment: If your code works without errors, you could ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: @coldspeed what I'm saying is that if your word is "word", out of all the anagrams, you can discard all the "wd*" because no word starts with "wd", so you don't need to check all the anagrams, you can prune some branches of the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed things up considerably by using a dictionary for checking membership instead of doing linear searches. The only "trick" is to devise a way to create keys for it such that it will be the same for anagrammatical words (and not for others).

In the code below this is being done by creating a sorted tuple from the letters in each word.

```
def anagramtastic(words):
    dct = {}
    for word in words:
        key = tuple(sorted(word))  # Identifier based on letters.
        dct.setdefault(key, []).append(word)

    # Return a list of all that had an anagram.
    return [words for words in dct.values() if len(words) > 1]

wordlist = ['act', 'cat', 'binary', 'brainy', 'case', 'aces',
            'aide', 'idea', 'earth', 'heart', 'tea', 'tee']

print('result:', anagramtastic(wordlist))
```

Output produced:

`result: [['act', 'cat'], ['binary', 'brainy'], ['case', 'aces'], ['aide', 'idea'], ['earth', 'heart']]`

Comment: martineau - thank you very much! Particularly considering this problem came from the thinkpython chapter on Tuples, this implementation answers exactly as I believe the solution is 'supposed' to be implemented

Comment: Daniel: That's interesting to hear...and you're welcome. I, of course, didn't know the exact chapter the problem came from, instead my reason for using tuples as the keys for a dictionary was based on the fact they were the simplest way of representing the data (a sorted sequence of all letters in each word) that could be used as a dictionary key. You could also use `key = ''.join(sorted(word))` to turn the sequence of them back into a string like @Snild Dolkow does in his answer—however without actually timing each approach, it's unclear to me whether that would be an improvement or not.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a dictionary of frozensets? Frozensets are immutable, meaning you can hash them for constant lookup. And when it comes to anagrams, what makes two words anagrams of each other is that they have the same letters with the same count. So you can construct a frozenset of {(letter, count), ...} pairs, and hash these for efficient lookup.

Here's a quick little function to convert a word to a multiset using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def word2multiset(word):
    return frozenset(Counter(word).items())
```

Now, given a list of words, populate your anagram dictionary like this:

```
list_of_words = [... ]

anagram_dict = defaultdict(set)
for word in list_of_words:
    anagram_dict[word2multiset(word)].add(word)
```

For example, when `list_of_words = ['hello', 'olleh', 'test', 'apple']`, this is the output of `anagram_dict` after a run of the loop above:

```
print(anagram_dict)
defaultdict(set,
            {frozenset({('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 2), ('o', 1)}): {'hello',
              'olleh'},
             frozenset({('e', 1), ('s', 1), ('t', 2)}): {'test'},
             frozenset({('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 1), ('p', 2)}): {'apple'}})
```

Comment: @martineau they're multisets, meaning the counts of the letters are preserved. Surely you'd credit me with knowing using sets here is a no-no :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, simply grouping the words by sorting their characters should be an efficient solution -- as you've already realized. The trick is to avoid comparing every word to all the other ones. A dict with the char-sorted string as key will make finding the right group for each word fast; a lookup/insertion will be O(log n).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding=utf8

from sys import stdin

groups = {}

for line in stdin:
    w = line.strip()
    g = ''.join(sorted(w))
    if g not in groups:
        groups[g] = []
    groups[g].append(w)

for g, words in groups.items():
    if len(words) > 1:
        print('%2d %-20s' % (len(words), g), ' '.join(words))
```

Testing on my words file (99171 words), it seems to work well:

```
anagram$ wc /usr/share/dict/words
 99171  99171 938848 /usr/share/dict/words
anagram$ time ./anagram.py < /usr/share/dict/words | tail
 2 eeeprsw              sweeper weepers
 2 brsu                 burs rubs
 2 aeegnrv              avenger engrave
 2 ddenoru              redound rounded
 3 aesy                 ayes easy yeas
 2 gimnpu               impugn umping
 2 deeiinsst            densities destinies
 2 abinost              bastion obtains
 2 degilr               girdle glider
 2 orsttu               trouts tutors

real    0m0.366s
user    0m0.357s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Comment: As I understand Python's internals, a `dict` uses a hash of its key to quickly look up its associated value. Would a simple binary lookup not be quicker? In plain C, I am (almost) sure it would, even if the hash itself can be binary-searched, because a hash always needs double-checking. But implementing the binary search *in* Python would come with a small overhead.

Comment: Maybe. But `dict` is usually good enough, and makes for much simpler code. I know it's always tempting to try to squeeze every cycle out, though... ;)

Comment: Note, while this may "look simple", sorting every word is O(NlogN), which happens to be worse than computing a frozen set (O(N)).

Comment: Your N there is the word length, though; log2(N) will be fairly small. I'd expect that the overhead for frozen sets is a bit higher, which might make up the difference. It's not obvious (at least to me) which would be faster in reality.

Comment: And when we're not sure, we test! So I tried replacing my `g = ''.join(sorted(w))` line with `g = frozenset(Counter(w).items())`. I also changed the print statement to not print the key, since that might be unfair for the frozen sets: `print('%2d' % (len(words)), ' '.join(words))`. Result: 0.361s for sorting, 1.558s for frozen sets.

Comment: coldspeed and Snild - both solutions worked so many thanks! coldspeed for some reason your solution worked in a test environment, but when I implemented against the full english dictionary test file the output included individual words and not just anagram groups. Also, at my stage of learning, the simpler code is transformationally easier for me to understand.